# Edit text input type phone - allow only 1 decimal

Tags: android, xamarin, text, edit

I am trying to find a way to only allow 1 decimal to put entered into an edit text whilst using the phone input type.

I know it automatically restricts to 1 decimal of using the numberDecimal input but I only want numerical keyboard and decimal available to the user. Therefore the phone input seems most appropriate but it allows the user to type as many '.' as they want.

Is there a way to prevent this? For example checking if the edit text already contains a '.' and if it does - not allowing another to be entered?

Comment: You can use an `InputFilter` for this. There are many questions here about how to use `InputFilter` to limit input in `EditText` fields. Just search for `InputFilter` and you should find a code example to do what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could listen the `textChanged` of `EditText`,then estimate if it already contains `.`.

If yes,keep the before value,if no,allow it input the new value.like below:

```
public class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity,ITextWatcher
{
   private string stringBefore;
   private int inputPosition;
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main);          
        EditText editText = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.edit);
        editText.AddTextChangedListener(this);
    }

    public override void OnRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, string[] permissions, [GeneratedEnum] Android.Content.PM.Permission[] grantResults)
    {
        Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

        base.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    }

    public void AfterTextChanged(IEditable s)
    {

    }

    public void BeforeTextChanged(ICharSequence s, int start, int count, int after)
    {
        stringBefore = s.ToString();  //the value before you input
        inputPosition= start;         //the postion you input

    }

    public void OnTextChanged(ICharSequence s, int start, int before, int count)
    {
        if (s.Length() > stringBefore.Length)    //estimate whether you are typing or deleting
        {
            if (s.CharAt(afterPosition) == '.' && stringBefore.Contains('.')) //estimate you are typing '.' and if already contains '.'
            {
                editText.Text = stringBefore;
                editText.SetSelection(stringBefore.Length - 1);
            }
        }

    }
 }
```